# Jquery - Dynamically resize container DIV width container when another DIV is loaded inside

Tags: jquery, scroll

how can I change width with Jquery of a DIV container when another DIV is loaded inside (via PHP)?

This is my HTML code

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="item"> Content 1 </div>
</div>
```

Now, I have a to populate dinamically the "container" for each page.
Another page may have this HTML code

```
<div id="container">
     <div class="item"> Content 1 </div>
     <div class="item"> Content 2 </div>
     <div class="item"> Content 3 </div>
</div>
```

"item" has float:left; 
I want all "items" in a row. How can I change the "container" width dynamically when a "item" is loaded inside?

I'm using a scrollbar Jquery plugin to scroll divs.

Please, help!

Comment: Please set up an example at http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you need something like this ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var youtWidth = 100;
    $('#container').width($('#container .item').length * yourWidth);
})
```

This count the elements inside the #container and set #container width to a multiple of the number of elements. In this example i keep 100px for each element.

Fabio

Answer (score 1):

You could calculate the width of the children and apply the total to the container, like this:

```
var contentWidth = 0;

$('#container .item').each( function() {
    // outerWidth(true) includes margins
    contentWidth += $(this).outerWidth(true);
});

$('#container').width( contentWidth );
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/SQASY/

---

Or, with some basic CSS, you could avoid doing it with JavaScript at all:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/YBKxn/1/

Answer (score 1):

If the items have different width you can always do:

```
var totalWidth = 0;
$('#container').children('.item').each(function(){
   totalWidth += $(this).outerWidth();
});

$('#container').width(totalWidth);
```